# Share constants across each WCF call between Client and Server

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5, wcf-proxy

A couple of integer constants are computed by WCF client before making the call to the WCF service. I would want these integer constants to be available on WCF service. Please note that I would not want them to be used as method arguments, because these constants are required irrespective of the method in the Service. Having the same argument for every method would be redundant.

To be clear, client keeps computing values for 'a' and 'b' before making a WCF service call. Once the call is made, throughout the entire call 'a' and 'b' can be accessed by the service. This is similar to using them as arguments of the method. Only difference here is that, 'a' and 'b' are needed by every method in the WCF service. So, I would prefer a better solution than adding 'a' and 'b' as arguments to every method in the WCF call.

So, let's say I have 3 methods in WCF service->

```
void Count1()

void Count2()

void Count3()
```

Client will compute different 'a' and 'b' values for each WCF method call. One solution is to keep the methods in this format.

```
void Count1(int a, int b)

void Count2(int a, int b)

void Count3(int a, int b)
```

But, I would like a better solution if possible.

Sorry about this long question.

Comment: Send them once they are computed, and keep them somewhere static in the WCF (as static members, or in MemoryCache, even in a database or a textfile - all depending on your needs).

Comment: @ZoharPeled When you say "send them", do you mean as arguments? I would not want to add 2 arguments across all my methods in WCF. These arguments are definitely needed by all the methods. I would need a more cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes, as arguments, but only once. When you get them into the WCF, store them on the server side

Comment: `integer constants are computed` this is a little bit confusing.  They are computed at compile time or will be computed at runtime?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Adding 2 arguments for every method in my service looks to be slightly unclean. I would need a better solution if possible.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The integer values are computed run-time by the client before each WCF call.

Comment: Are there multiple clients each computing a different value? Or just a single client computing values for a series of calls?

Comment: You should share more info for better assistance.

Comment: @Kevin Not really. But, I am not sure how it matters. Let's imagine something like this-> A single client keeps computing separate values for 'a' and 'b' before each WCF call. These 'a' and 'b' integers will be used as constants across the entire WCF service call.

Comment: Now you say they are calculated before each call to the WCF - in the question you wrote they are constants (so I thought you calculate them once in the client and then keep using the same values). Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: The difference is, if there are multiple clients computing different values, keeping the values separate across a series of calls for each client could become a nightmare. For a single client, you could create a new method on the WCF service that updates the values that will be used across the next series of calls (until the next recompute of the values).

Comment: I am sorry about the limited information in the question guys. I hope my edit might clear most of the questions raised.

Comment: `Client will compute different 'a' and 'b' values for each WCF method call.` So how do you think to deliver that **different** values through channel without passing as argument?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I was hoping something like CallContext.

Comment: What  you about are bothering?  Performance, clean code, ... ?

Comment: Both, if possible :)

Comment: Have you considered adding them to the header of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "Request" class for your service as a data contract, and include in this request `a`, `b` and any other value(s) you might want to get from the client. A basic request would only keep `a` and `b`, but other requests might derive from it.
This way you only send one parameter to the service for every method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal mode for WCF services, however, you can create a "sticky" service class that last for the duration of the client. Note that the `InstanceContextMode` is set to session meaning that this class instance will hang around as long as the client has not disconnected/abandoned or a timeout does not occurr (you will need to send a periodic pulse in order to keep it awake if your client is not chatty). Also, pay attention to the `ConcurrencyMode`.

```
[ServiceBehavior(Name = "MyStickyServicee",
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

public class MyStickyService : IMyStickyService, IDisposable
{
}
```

Here is some more information on [instancing in wcf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/instancing).